# Take down Product Request

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there any extension or plugin that can help viewers or customers to report a product from front end to help notify admin that the product has issues.

We are hosting products that are customized and do not wish to list products with copyrights issue on our platform.

Any guidance or if there is any extension that we can modify or use as guide to make this addon will be helpful

Comment: Are you using product reviews on the site?

Comment: Nope. But i wanted a extension like if anyone sees any product that is illegal or not meeting policy standards then the guest can report that product.

Comment: Im not aware of any, my thought if you are not using product reviews would be to modify the review functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this quite simply with a js/jquery popup form using ajax to send you the notification.

You would add a simple button or text link to your product view template that triggers the popup.

The form would contain a simple note and action button to allow the user to flag this product as a copyright violation, as well as any other user info you require. I would also build in some kind of entry/captcha code to avoid spam.

I often also use twitter for these kind of adhoc notifications, you receive both a twitter DM and an email.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any extensions to do this for you.

My answer if you are not using product reviews would be to modify Magentos core review functionality.

Change post review to post copyright violation request. Then edit the review form template so the wording fits in with what you want it to do.

These could be added to a product also you will get an email when one has been posted, you could then follow up the request and disable a product if it has breached copyright infringement.